# add a scrollbar to a window in LablGtk2

Tags: window, scrollbar, ocaml

I want to add a scrollbar to a window in LablGtk2.
I wrote as below.

```
 let w = GWindow.window
         ~width:width
         ~height:height
         ~allow_grow:true
         ~allow_shrink:true
         ~decorated:true
         () in
 ignore(GRange.scrollbar `HORIZONTAL ~packing:w#add ~show:true ());
```

However, a window(w in the code) did't show a scrollbar.
How can I make a scrollbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrolled_window` from [`GBin`](http://lablgtk.forge.ocamlcore.org/refdoc/GBin.html) module.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Just use `GBin.scrolled_window` instead of `GWindow.window`, by merely substituting the latter by the former. Maybe some arguments should be removed. But otherwise should work just out of box.

Comment: Right that's what I'm saying, can you give an example of the swap.

Comment: `let w = GBin.scrolled_window
         ~width:width
         ~height:height in`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could do. I have a related question. In case I want to add scrollbars to a window only when a window is shortened, what should I do? I could't find a method which works so. In this case, a window must have a optional argument "allow_shrink".